# Pascal's triangle in python with known row

Tags: python

*So I have here Pascal's triangle. I understood the logic behind it but for whatever reason I couldnt deal with when giving me a known
row. I knew how to build from n rows but not how to build when a row
is given to you to the next one... I tried here but I got stuck ... my
code isn't complete because I couldnt find a way to sum each time
above numbers. Any idea?*

```
def generate_pascal_row(row):
"""Generate the next row of Pascal's triangle."""
    list_result=[]
    for x in row:
        list_result2 = []
        for j in x:
            return list_result     
print(generate_pascal_row([1, 2, 1]))  # => [1, 3, 3, 1]
print(generate_pascal_row([1, 4, 6, 4, 1]))  # => [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
print(generate_pascal_row([]))  # => [1]
```

Comment: "I knew how to build from n rows but not how to build when a row is given to you to the next one." Well, do you know how to solve the problem with pencil and paper? Say for example that the input is `[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]`. **What values should be added together**? What is the **rule that tells you** that?

Comment: yep. it is about the code tho ...

Comment: "I knew how to build from n rows" then you must know the rules to generate line n+1 from line n, or not? Just do the same for the given line.

Comment: You need to add successive pairs of numbers in `row` together and append them to a list which initially contains 1. Use indices to grab these pairs. Don't forget to tack on the final 1 at the end.

Comment: "it is about the code tho ... " It is about the **question**. We need a question that is asked precisely; "I got stuck; any idea?" is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). So we need to understand *what steps* you expect the code to take, before we can understand *why* there is a problem with writing the code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am trying to access to the list and sum numbers from the right and left, as Pascal's triangle concept indicates. I did not figure out how to use indices to do that.

Comment: @JohnColeman that is what i am trying to figure out

Comment: If `i` is the index for one number then `i+1` is the index for the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def generate_pascal_row(row):
    list_result=[]
    if len(row) == 0:
        list_result.append(1)
        return list_result
    list_result.append(row[0])
    for i in range(0,len(row)-1):
        list_result.append(row[i]+row[i+1])
    list_result.append(row[len(row)-1])
    return list_result

print(generate_pascal_row([1, 2, 1]))  # => [1, 3, 3, 1]
print(generate_pascal_row([1, 4, 6, 4, 1]))  # => [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
print(generate_pascal_row([]))  # => [1]
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1]
```